# Argh! How do you correctly update the SelectedValue of a ComboBox on initialization?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

Consider the following code.  This is a simplification of a process that I have implemented within a User Control that I've created.

```
//MyUserControl Constructor
public MyUserControl(field, value)
{
    InitializeComponents();
    string cType = resolveControlType(field);
    switch (cType)
    {
        ...
        case "ComboBox":  AddComboBox(field, value);
        ...
    }
}

AddComboBox(string fieldID, object value)
{
    ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
    cbo.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
    cbo.ValueMember = "ValueMember";

    //We set the DataSource to a DataTable
    cbo.DataSource = DBCaller.GetListAsDataTable(fieldID);
    this.Controls.Add(cbo);
    cbo.SelectedValue = value; //<-- Weird stuff happening here?!
                               //    If you don't break here, it  
                               //    doesn't look like the correct 
                               //    record is selected.
                               //    However, add a breakpoint,
                               //    scroll through cbo's properties
                               //    and this assignment will work
                               //    properly when you continue?!
}
```

My problem is that when I assign the value to the control, the text in the ComboBox displays the first item from my DataSource table.

However, if I put a breakpoint on the `cbo.SelectedValue = value;` line and, using Intellisense, scroll through the properties associated with my ComboBox, something initializes on the ComboBox that fixes this problem.  Once I continue running the code, my form loads with the proper value displayed on the ComboBox.

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: When you finish debugging and your app is fully running, the selected value is still correct?

Comment: @YairNevet.  Correct.  If I break on the assignment line, before the assignment takes place, and scroll through the properties of `cbo` using intellisense, everything works fine.  However, if I don't debug, my Combo displays the text of the first record in my DataTable.  I assume the value is correct, however, the text being shown on the control is incorrect.  That assumption is only speculative, however, and not verified.

Comment: Code doesn't show it, but are you adding `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: Yes.  Actually, the SelectedIndexChanged event is a lambda statement, right after the DataSource is assigned.  FYI, within the event statement, I never cancel the event.  I just check to see if the first row is being selected, so I can prompt the user for a new record entry screen-- this never happens on initialization, though.

Comment: @RLH Can you post the code for event handler? Also (as a test) can you attach the handler after you assign `SelectedValue `

Comment: Let me give that a try.  In fact, as a test I'll remove it all together.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: I no longer have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event-- it's been completely commented out and I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found how to solve your problem but to explain why it's so is not easy. I've found some thing interesting here. First, I would like to say that I've found at least 2 ways to set the things in order. Here are the code for those 2 ways:

```
//Solution 1
//Simply you have to add the ComboBox to the parent control first
//before assigning its DataSource
this.Controls.Add(cbo);   //<---- This goes first
cbo.DataSource = DBCaller.GetListAsDataTable(fieldID); //<--- This goes after
cbo.SelectedValue = value;

//Solution 2
//This is very strange and interesting, you can also add your ComboBox to 
//the parent control after assigning its DataSource (as in your code).
//But you have to ACCESS to the BindingContext property of your ComboBox
//I would like to emphasize the ACCESS, you can perform any kind of access (Read and Write).
//Here are some examples of such access:
cbo.DataSource = DBCaller.GetListAsDataTable(fieldID);
this.Controls.Add(cbo);  //<--- like in your code, this is placed here after the DataSource is assigned
//here you can ACCESS the BindingContext
var whatEver = cbo.BindingContext;//READ access
if(cbo.BindingContext == null) Text = "????"; //READ access and of course it's not null
cbo.BindingContext = new BindingContext();//WRITE access
cbo.SelectedValue = value; //<---- This should be placed here after all.
```

I found the second solution is very strange and not easy to explain, although the first solution can be understandable (at least at the time I had not found the second).

Comment: I'll give you the answer mark, but I just found a solution about 10 seconds ago.  In my case, right after I setup the DataSource, I called `cbo.CreateControl()`.  I think the CreateControl method finishes initializing all data, text and drawing areas.  I assume this is normally called after a control is displayed (or being displayed) on a form.

Comment: @RLH sounds interesting. You can even try setting the `SelectedValue` when it's surely `Visible` by registering `VisibleChanged` and check it there. Just tested that approach and it also works.

Comment: Yes, I had considered something like that but that felt more like a "hack" than a legitimate answer.  There has to be a reason why the ComboBox behaves this way, and I'm interested in that reason too.

Answer (score 0):

i meet it too. but my combo is in a panel still not added to form. now i find this way at last:

```
            //FAILED cboField.SelectedValue = value;
            //FAILED cboField.HandleCreated += ;
            //FAILED cboField.SelectedItem = item;
            //FAILED cboField.SelectedIndex = indexOfItem;
            cboField.BindingContextChanged += (s1, e2) => {
                cboField.SelectedValue = value;
            };
```

you needn't try all those failed ways again.